# Is it possible to get account activities log from google adword api and facebook ads manager api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want get account activities from google adsword api and facebook ads manager api. So Is it possible to get such activities data from this api ?

Comment: Please specify what specific kinds of "activities" that you are trying to access via these APIs so that people may assist you.

Answer (score 1):

For Faceboo, the Activities endpoint should be good for you. This should works with several edge (AdAccounts, AdSet,...). As example, for an AdAccounts:

```
act_XXX/activities&fields=object_id,object_name,event_type,event_time
```

See the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-activity
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/activities
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/activities/

hope this help